# Add Variables to Tuple Using list looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to add 5 to tuple elements using loop and list.

```
t=(10,20,30,40,50)
lst = []
for i in t:
    lst[i]=t[i]+5

t = tuple(lst)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python discourages using indices this way unless you really need them. When you write `for i in t:`,  `i` will be the values of `t` not the indices, so `t[i]` is probably not what you want — that will be `t[10]`, `t[20]`, etc...

The pythonic way is to use a comprehension:

```
t=(10,20,30,40,50)
t = tuple(n + 5 for n in t)
print(t)
# (15, 25, 35, 45, 55)
```

If you *really* want to use a loop, you can just append to the list as you go:

```
t=(10,20,30,40,50)

lst = []
for n in t:
    lst.append(n+5)

t = tuple(lst)
print(t)
# (15, 25, 35, 45, 55)
```